# How to change a nested object value of a redux state

Tags: javascript, redux

I have the following state

```
const state = {
  courses: [],
  series: [],
  course: {
      title: 'testing',
      course_notes: [
    {
      id: 1,
      note: "one" // want to edit this
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      note: "two"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

I want to change `state.course.course_notesp[0].name`

I've never fully understood how this works, read a lot of tutorials, I feel I know how it works but it always trips me up. This is what I am trying

```
const m = {
  ...state, 
  course: {
    course_notes:[
      ...state.course.course_notes,
      state.course.course_notes.find(n => n.id === 1).note = "edited"
    ]
  }
}
```

That seems to add `edited` as an extra node. `state.course.course_notes.length` ends up being `3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the spread operator for arrays like you would for objects.

Assume you have an object

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

If you say:

```
{...obj, a: 2}
```

What you are saying is:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, a: 2 }
```

The property `a` is defined twice, but the second one overrrides the first one.

If you do something similar for an array, however, the result would be different:

```
const arr = [1, 2];
const newArr = [...arr, arr[0]];

// here the result would be [1, 2, 1]
```

This is why when you are saying:

```
course_notes:[
  ...state.course.course_notes,
  state.course.course_notes.find(n => n.id === 1).note = "edited"
]
```

what it does is add an extra element to the array.

What you should do is instead create a modified version of the array, for example using `map`

```
course_notes: state.course.course_notes.map(el => {
    if (el.id === 1) {
        el.note = 'edited';
    }
    return el;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you could modify the state of your store to update one element of course_notes.

If we assumed the ids to be unique, I would map the previous array modifying the element with id 1.

```
....
course_notes: state.course.course_notes.map(x => x === 1
  ? { ...x, note: 'edited' } 
  : x
)
...
```